# Linux Script, for on files of a directory

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I need to do a shell script that lauch some parameter above a files in a directory.

I am using something like

```
for f in *.tmp
do
        echo  $f
        sleep 5
done
```

My problem is that during the execution of the for, the number of files in the directory may change. And the for only applies in the files listed at the time of first execution.

Any Ideas ??
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the files in an array

```
files=(*.tmp)
```

Then use an infinite while loop, and break out when a condition is met:

```
i=0
while true; do
    do_something with "${files[i]}"
    current_files=(*.tmp)
    magic_handwaving -- some code to compare "files" with "current_files" \
        that will append new files to "files"
    (( ++i == ${#files[@]} )) && break
done
echo all files processed
```